# how to bind clockPicker value

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

So since I couldn't find any angular4 clockpickers I decided to use the jQuery one but I can't bind the selected time to a variable and I need that so I can manipulate them on my typescript component.. here is my code

that `console.log(this.value)` does show me the selected value but I cannot assign it to my declared variables.

**Component:**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  jQuery("#timePicker").clockpicker({ placement: 'bottom', donetext: 'Done', autoclose: true, vibrate: true, })
    .find('input').change(function (a) {
      console.log(a);
      console.log(this.value)
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="timeHolder" 
     id="timePicker" 
     data-placement="right" 
     data-align="top" 
     data-autoclose="true">
  <input type="text" 
         [(ngModel)]="setTime" 
         (input)="valuechange($event)" /> 
    {{setTime}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function with function keyword it changes the value of `this`. So instead as recommended @developer033 you should use arrow functions which don't change the value of `this`. You should use the following code :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery("#timePicker").clockpicker({ placement: 'bottom', donetext: 'Done', autoclose: true, vibrate: true, })
    .find('input').change((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
        // use that to access angular variables
        this.setTime = e.currentTarget.value;
    });
}
```

Comment: IMO, it's better to use `arrow-functions`.

Comment: @developer033 Agreed. Before I didn't want to change the jquery code but now i realise it's a lot better to modify jquery code